# Inserting/embedding a file to a DOCX file - determining file-type

Tags: .net, ms-word, docx, openxml-sdk

Let's say I have an API which lets clients insert a file into a DOCX template, they just pass a path to the file. If it's an image I just want to add an image to the file, if it's something life RTF/DOC then I can maybe embed it so the content is visible, if it's some other type like MP3 or PDF then it might simply embed with an icon.

I guess I could simply look at file extension, but even then I think I might need the correct file-type string, I see code snippets like `mainPart.AddEmbeddedObjectPart("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.oleObject")` and wonder how I can map file-extension to type. Is there a handy page with such things?

And, I assume I do need different logic for pictures/other types? It would be weird to embed a picture?

Comment: for authoritative purposes, have a look at the [IANA media type repository](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/index.html). the registration docs are somewhat unstructured, look for 'file extension' or 'file type' and you will usually get this info needed. for more suggestions refer to [this so question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609208/complete-list-of-mime-type-file-extension-mapping).

Comment: Embedding a picture is possible in a word document. Have you found some solutions ?