# complete list of mime-type <-> file extension mapping

Tags: http, mime-types, file-extension

I can't find a complete list of mime-type mappings on the internet.
I would like to have a list that refers a file extension to every existing mime type.

The list of all mime-types can be found here: 
http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types

but that resource doesn't include the file extension mapping.

I googled a while and couldn't find a mapping list with all mime-types. Only lists with most common ones. In all lists I found for example this entry is missing:

```
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document   ->  .docx
```

Does someone know a resource where to find a complete mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just want to let you know, there is a new class for this in .NET Framework 4.5

```
System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filename);
```

source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mimemapping(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 37):

Using Jürgen's mime.types link and a little command line magic, you can generate the list you want very quickly:

```
wget -qO- http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types | egrep -v ^# | awk '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) {print $i" "$1}}' | sort
```

Comment: npm module based from your answer https://github.com/miguelmota/mime-ext

Answer (score 10):

You have to install apache or nginx or something else and look at the mime.types file.

```
# MIME type                 Extensions
# application/3gpp-ims+xml
# application/activemessage
application/andrew-inset            ez
# application/applefile
application/applixware              aw
application/atom+xml                atom
application/atomcat+xml             atomcat
# application/atomicmail
application/atomsvc+xml             atomsvc
# application/auth-policy+xml
...
more, more, more over 1300 mine-types.
```

Comment: .. or fetch the `mime.types` file from a repository like [http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types)

Comment: but only the ones not commented out include a mapping. the other are left blank in that file.

Comment: commented types usualy didn't support by browsers, so you haven't to use it.

Comment: @juergen d: yep, but I guess you won't find more than that. File extensions are OS-specific and just meant to _indicate_ which format a file could have, not to guarantee that it does. Afaik there simply is no official standard for such kind of mapping.

Comment: Well I guess that list is complete enough then. Thanks.