# Get default / preferred file extension

Tags: unix

I can identify file types with [`file`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_%28command%29) command. Can I get what is default (preferred) extension for the file?

For example for

```
tmp_206.file: GIF image data, version 89a, 17 x 17
tmp_202.file: ASCII text, with very long lines, with no line terminators
```

it would be `.gif` and `.txt`

I know extensions do not matter for UNIX, but they do matter for me

Comment: There is no such thing as default extension. But: HTTP servers try to map extensions to mime types. You can [re-use that mapping to pick a likely extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609208/complete-list-of-mime-type-file-extension-mapping).

Comment: You can get the mime type with `file --mime-type <filename>`.

Answer (score 2):

Some file types support more than 1 extension like jpe, jpeg, jpg etc for jpeg files.

What you can do is to get mime type first using:

```
mimleType=$(awk -F';' 'NF>1{print $1}' < <(file -bi logo.jpeg))
```

Then use this awk to get file extension:

```
awk -v mt=$mimeType '$1==mt{print $2}' /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/mime.types
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
jpeg
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a reasonably limited set of extensions, creating a mapping from `file` output to your preferred extension is not hard.

```
case $(file - <"$file") in
  '-: GIF image'* ) ext=gif ;;
  '-: ASCII text'* ) ext=txt ;;
  # etc
esac
```