# Get file MIME type in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I know when uploading a file I can use `file.type` to get the MIME, but in Javascript itself am I able to get a MIME type just from an extensio?

e.g.

```
<script>
var file = "myfile.jpg";
alert(**FILE'S MIME**);
</script>
```

Comment: You mean something like [this](/questions/18299806/how-to-check-file-mime-type-with-javascript-before-upload)?

Comment: No because that method is looking at an actual file. My question is if JS can tell me the MIME type from a file name only.

Comment: The file extension may have very little to do with the MIME type of the contents, but look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609208/complete-list-of-mime-type-file-extension-mapping)

Comment: A file extension is not equivalent to a file extension, but in general no, JavaScript cannot do this. The non-standard `navigator.mimeTypes` is the closest thing to it in a browser, but it only lists those registered by plugins. You could define your own list though.

Comment: If you want to take it from str: `var file="myfile.jpg";    extension = myfile.substring(myfile.lastIndexOf('.'); `

Comment: Ok, so answer is no, not without defining all the extensions/mimes somewhere. Thanks!

Comment: You can construct File objects in some browsers, and i would expect `file.type` to reflect the extension when you do.